Please I beg support to flag a radio button in Python using PyPDF2
Below is my code. I'm able to fill out the text field in the PDF file, but when it comes to flagging the radio button, I do not find any way to fix.
The name of the radio button field is Case d'option 1, and I have five (5) button with the same name.
In the PDF looks like the attached image, there is a question and five radio boxes; only one can be flag. How can I flag the first ( or the second )?
the radio button
I tried to read the source PDF, I'm expecting to be able to flag the first of the five circle radio boxes
import PyPDF2
import os
print (os.getcwd())
os.chdir("D:\\User\\Desktop\\fill_PDF_PY")

from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

###########################################################
reader = PdfReader("c3.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()

page = reader.pages[0]

nomeid= "test"

writer.add_page(page)

writer.update_page_form_field_values(
    writer.pages[0], {"Champ de texte 1": nomeid
                    , "Champ de texte 5": "works1"
                    , "Champ de texte 6": "works2"
                    , "Champ de texte 8": "works3"
                    , "Champ de texte 144": "data in"
                    , "Champ de texte 143": "data out"
                   # , "Case d'option 1": {"/Opt" : [True,False,False,False,False]} # not works attempt 1
                    , "Case d'option 1": {'/T': "Case d'option 1", '/FT': '/Btn', '/Ff': 49152, '/V': '/1',
                                         '/Kids': [(206, 0, 2373315004816), (207, 0, 2373315004816), (202, 0, 2373315004816), (204, 0, 2373315004816), (205, 0, 2373315004816)],
                                         '/Opt': [ 1, 'Choix2', 'Choix3', 'Choix4', 'Choix5']},     # not works attempt 2                 
                      }
)


with open("filled-out5.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)


PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

The problem has been solved, use pypdf instead of pyPDF2.
